# mysql query replaces html tags with _ underscores

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, oscommerce

I just switched an old oscommerce installation from mysql_ to mysqli_ (by changing database.php files/functions). Some SELECT statements that previously returned: 
`<p>Bla bla <br /> blah</p>` 
now return 
`_p_Bla bla _br __ blah_/p_`

does anyone have a quick fix, or do i need to dig deeper?

Comment: Sounds like a string replace of some sort. Can you find the query itself and post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it:

old function did:

```
return trim(stripslashes($string));
```

new function includes:

`return trim(tep_sanitize_string(stripslashes($string)));`

the sanitize function included `preg_replace("/[<>]/", '_', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

mysql query replaces **absolutely nothing**
So, you have to dig deeper, into *your own code* that does whatever replacements, and take them out